# How to compare current row with previous and next n rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to check if the value of the current row is less than the previous n rows as well as the next n rows and store the result in a new column.

for example I am trying to get a table such as following where n=2.

```
     a     b
0    15    False
1    16    False
2    13    True
3    17    False
4    20    False
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which of the [windowing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html#expanding-window-functions) functions have you tried to use? [Show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us the code, even if it is not yet working as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first calculate the previous minimum using the rolling window, then we reverse the dataframe and calculate the next minimum using rolling on the reversed dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10))})

n = 2 
df['less_than_neighbors'] = False
df_reversed = df[::-1]
df['min_prev'] = df['value'].rolling(window=n, min_periods=n, closed='left').min()
df['min_next'] = df_reversed['value'].rolling(window=n, min_periods=n, closed='left').min()

df.loc[ ( (df['value']  < df['min_prev']) & (df['value']  < df['min_next'])), 'less_than_neighbors'] = True

#df.drop(columns=['min_prev', 'min_next'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using numpy arrays, col_name is a variable with your values, new_col_name is a name of your Boolean column:

```
   def checker(df, col_name, new_col_name, n):
       vals = df[col_name].to_numpy()
       bools = [(vals[i] < vals[max(i - n, 0) : i]).all() 
           and (vals[i] < vals[i + 1 : min(i + n + 1, vals.size)]).all() 
           for i in range(vals.size)]
       df[new_col_name] = bools
       return df
```